# Will SSRS User rights be over-ridden by Windows account?

Tags: ssrs, authorization

If a Reporting Services user group has all rights on SRS Report Server folder, and one of the group member's Windows Account has been added to the folder with Browse only, will SQL server cause that member's rights to be over-ridden by the Window's account Browse rights?

Comment: Rights are additive, that is the sum of the rights determines the ability of the user.  If a right is specifically denied that takes precedence.

Comment: Thanks - that provides some clarification. My user is a member of a group that has been given ALL rights on an SRS folder - including a subfolder. I can't figure why she gets an error when trying to create a datasource - and the error refers to her Windows account instead of the user group. Thanks much for your reply.

Comment: Add those details (the exact error message) to your question, please.